# Reshape matrix from 3d to 2d keeping specific order

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to resize a matrix under the form let's say 4x3x5, to a 2d matrix of 20x3 but while preserving the order as illustrated below :

[image: Original Matrix]
[image: Reshaped Matrix]

The function `reshape()` does not keep this particular order, how could I achieve this the simplest way possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's solve these problems of concatenating and cutting across the third dimension once and for all!

**Part I (3D to 2D) :** Concatenate along the columns and across the `3rd` dim of a `3D` array, `A` to form a `2D` array -

```
reshape(permute(A,[1 3 2]),[],size(A,2))
```

**Part II (2D to 3D)  :** Cut a `2D` array `B` after every `N` rows to form `3D` slices of a `3D` array -

```
permute(reshape(B,N,size(B,1)/N,[]),[1 3 2])
```

Sample run -

**Part I (3D to 2D)**

```
>> A
A(:,:,1) =
     4     1     4     3
     8     4     6     4
     8     5     6     1
A(:,:,2) =
     9     4     4     1
     2     2     9     7
     1     5     9     3
A(:,:,3) =
     4     4     7     7
     5     9     6     6
     9     3     5     2
>> B = reshape(permute(A,[1 3 2]),[],size(A,2));
>> B
B =
     4     1     4     3
     8     4     6     4
     8     5     6     1
     9     4     4     1
     2     2     9     7
     1     5     9     3
     4     4     7     7
     5     9     6     6
     9     3     5     2
```

**Part II (2D to 3D)**

```
>> N = 3;
>> permute(reshape(B,N,size(B,1)/N,[]),[1 3 2])
ans(:,:,1) =
     4     1     4     3
     8     4     6     4
     8     5     6     1
ans(:,:,2) =
     9     4     4     1
     2     2     9     7
     1     5     9     3
ans(:,:,3) =
     4     4     7     7
     5     9     6     6
     9     3     5     2
```